# Subset simulated data

Tags: r

I have a simulated data has 7 studies and it is really very huge file. It contains columns of:

```
> SIM.data
TIME   CONC STUDY
   0      2     7
 0.5      5     8
   1      8     9
   2      8     9
   0     10    10 
 0.5     12    10 
   5     15    10
```

I want to discard TIME AND CONCENTRATION data of STUDIES 7,8 9 for TIMES less than or euqal 1 hour. how can I use the subset function to do this in one shot? like;

```
SIMdata <- subset (SIMdata, discard data for TIMES <= 1 hour for STDUY <10 only)
```

OR alternatively,

```
SIMdata <- subset (SIMdata, consider TIME>1 for STUDY <10 but all for STUDY >=10)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot discard only TIME values, but you can set them to NA:

```
SIM.data$TIME<-ifelse(SIM.data$STUDY<10 & SIM.data$TIME<=1, NA, SIM.data$TIME)
```

If you want to remove all rows where such condition is satisfied,

```
newData <- SIM.data[!(SIM.data$STUDY<10 & SIM.data$TIME<=1),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this also

```
   dataSub <- simdata$study<10 & simdata$time<1

    SIMdata2 <- simdata[!dataSub,]
```

Comment: Thnak you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This will "discard" rows that meets those criteria:

```
SIM.data <- subset (SIM.data, !(TIME <= 1 $ STUDY <10) )
```